# Jupyter Notebook / Python - Enabling matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Within a Jupyter Notebook, why is it necessary to include this line:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

This seems to be required for matplotlib to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** necessary to include the line `%matplotlib inline` in a jupyter notebook.

Introducing this line selects the backend for matplotlib plotting to be the `inline` backend. This simplifies a lot of things, such as showing figures. If this backend is selected, a figure will automatically appear in the output once it is meantionned in a cell.

Without having selected the `%matplotlib inline` backend, you would need to call `plt.show()` to show the matplotlib output.